# Return Map or Convert to Map? word-count elixir

Tags: elixir

Working on the exercism word-count problem in Elixir.  The object is to return a map with word-count of each word in the sentence.  i.e. if string "one fish two fish red fish blue fish" is the input the output should be `%{ "one" => 1 ,  "fish" => 4 ,  "two" => 1 ,  "red" => 1 ,  "blue" => 1 }`

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
iex(14)> sentence = "one fish two fish red fish blue fish"
"one fish two fish red fish blue fish"
iex(15)> String.split(sentence)                                                                         
["one", "fish", "two", "fish", "red", "fish", "blue", "fish"]
iex(16)> String.split(sentence) |> Enum.group_by(fn(x) -> x end)
%{"blue" => ["blue"], "fish" => ["fish", "fish", "fish", "fish"],
  "one" => ["one"], "red" => ["red"], "two" => ["two"]}
```

How do I iterate over this map and run Enum.count on the values?  I tried `Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, Enum.count(v)} end)`, but that returns a list of tuples `[{"blue", 1}, {"fish", 4}, {"one", 1}, {"red", 1}, {"two", 1}]`.  Do I need to do a conversion of tuples to map or is there a better way? If I need to convert tuples to a map type, how do I do that?

I'm new to Elixir and Erlang, so if someone can tell me why when you pass a map into an Enum.map function you get back a list of tuples instead of a map that would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert a list of pairs (tuples with 2 elements) using [Enum.into/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#into/2):

```
[{"blue", 1}, {"fish", 4}, {"one", 1}, {"red", 1}, {"two", 1}] |> Enum.into(%{})
```

You can [Enum.reduce/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) into a new map instead to prevent an additional enumeration:

```
String.split(sentence)
|> Enum.group_by(fn(x) -> x end)
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {k, v}, acc -> Map.put(acc, k, Enum.count(v)) end)
```

Maps are explicitly converted into a list of pairs in their implementation for the Enumerable protocol: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.1.1/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2619

You can count the words in the list in a single pass with Enum.reduce and [Map.update/4](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Map.html#update/4) too:

```
String.split(sentence)
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn word, acc -> Map.update(acc, word, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)
```

Comment: Yep that works.  Can you help me understand how Map.update works?  What are all the inputs?  What is the &?

Comment: The inputs are explained in the docs that I linked. You can read the docs for &() here http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1 . `&(&1 + 1)` is the same as `fn x -> x + 1 end`

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I believe I get it now.  The last option you provide is shorter, but it doesn't read well due to the magic numbers.  My work and I value readability over cleverness so my vote would be for the `group_by` and then `reduce` option.  Just for confirmation, the first 1 in Map.update is an initial or default value, the second 1 is not a 1 at all (it's the current value of the key value pair in the map), and the third 1 is the increment value of 1 if the key is present.  Correct?

Comment: You are correct. The first argument (1) is the initial value if the key does not exist in the map. The ``&(&1 + 1)` is a function that increments the current value (`&1`) by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Note: With `elixir-1.10` you can leverage `Enum.frequencies` function.

```
"one fish two fish red fish blue fish" 
|> String.split(" ")
|> Enum.frequencies
```

This way you can do it all with pipe-operator